# Missing imports in Spring Keycloak auth server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently working through this guide to learn about the integration of keycloak into spring boot:
https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app

I created my project with https://start.spring.io/ and added all needed dependencies from the tutorial.

I also implemented the getters needed in the KeycloakServerProperties.java, so in now looks like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keycloak.server")
public class KeycloakServerProperties {
    String contextPath = "/auth";
    String realmImportFile = "baeldung-realm.json";
    AdminUser adminUser = new AdminUser();
 
    public AdminUser getAdminUser(){
        return this.adminUser;
    }
    
    public String getRealmImportFile(){
        return this.realmImportFile;
    }

    public String getContextPath(){
        return this.contextPath;
    }
 
    public static class AdminUser {
        String username = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
 
        public String getUsername(){
            return this.username;
        }

        public String getPassword(){
            return this.password;
        }      
    }
}
```

My problem now lies within my EmbeddedKeycloakApplication.java and my EmbeddedKeycloakConfig.java

There are plenty of errors a la "Name cannot be resolved to a type"
I uploaded the project as-is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iuxeBcfX_cmSVIfE8tBftmHLfStCyCF6/view?usp=sharing

I think that I am missing a mandatory package or an import that the tutorial doesn't mention.

Also, googling for the typenames didn't help me.

Which imports am I missing?

Comment: Hi ! Can you please copy and paste the log in a comment

Comment: There is no log since I am unable to launch anything. These are my errors:
https://imgur.com/a/B5XIM2F